# How to convert Mp3 to Amr Audio Format in Java

Tags: java, audio, mp3, media, amr

I'm writing a Java application and I'd like to convert Mp3 to Amr audio format.
So, I could'nt success since there are no documentations or libraries to help.
if possible, could you any hint about how to process, with examples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found this library called jave you can convert a media format to another format. you can see the library [here](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/manual.php)

Here is a sample code that I did using the said plugin

```
Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
    EncodingAttributes attributes = new EncodingAttributes();
    attributes.setFormat("wav");
    AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();
    audio.setBitRate(new Integer(64000));
    audio.setChannels(new Integer(1));
    audio.setSamplingRate(new Integer(22050));
    attributes.setAudioAttributes(audio);

    File source = new File("mysong.mp3");
    File target = new File("mysong.wav");
    try {
        encoder.encode(source, target, attributes);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InputFormatException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (EncoderException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The code I posted basically converts the mp3 to wav

Comment: When I use this sample code, it gives this exception. Is it normal?   "it.sauronsoftware.jave.EncoderException: Error while opening codec for output stream #0.0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height"

Comment: looks like I missed something. I am not in my dev pc as of this moment, please try to refer to the documentation

Comment: @chburd I have used That said api what do you mean by NazGul exceptions your answer is out of topic.also it did not give me any problems at all. regarding my answer The error is that I forgot to include the codec to be used. just provide your own codec by, audio.setCodect("nameofcodechere"); and also adjust the bitrates.

Comment: sorry for my stupid jokes. read Lord of the Rings from Tolkien to know who is Sauron

Answer (score 1):

JAVE is a well known and very useful tool for converting format, but it has some problems, EncoderException is one of it.

I created a project to make it updated and easy to use.

https://github.com/dadiyang/jave

[English Documentation Here](https://github.com/dadiyang/jave/blob/master/README-en.md)

This tool is mainly used to convert the AMR to MP3 format for playing in the audio tag of HTML5. It wrapper ffmpeg, and make it has cross platform feature.

Based on the JAVE project which relies on ffmpeg, this tool can be used to all ffmpeg supported format conversion. See JAVE official documentation for details.

The only thing you need to do is:

Inclue Maven Depandency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.dadiyang</groupId>
    <artifactId>jave</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

And Invoke AudioUtils.amrToMp3 Method

```
public void amrToMp3()  {
    File source = new File("testAudio.amr");
    File target = new File("testAudio.mp3");
    AudioUtils.amrToMp3(source, target);
}
```

May it helps for you.

Aha, don't forget to star.